# Oozie - Is there a way to have only a single instance of the java action executing on the entire cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

When I look at my logs, I see that my oozie java actions are actually running on multiple machines.

I assume that is because they're wrapped inside m/r job? (is this correct)

Is there a way to have only a single instance of the java action executing on the entire cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java action runs inside an Oozie "launcher" job, with just **one YARN "map" container**.

The trick is that every YARN job requires an **application master (AM) container** for coordination.
So you end up with 2 containers, `_0001` for the AM and `_0002` for the Oozie action, probably on different machines.

To control the resource allocation for each one, you can set the following Action properties to override your `/etc/hadoop/conf/*-site.xml` config and/or hard-coded defaults (which are specific to each version and each distro, by the way):

- `oozie.launcher.yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb`
- `oozie.launcher.yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts` *(to align the max heap size with the global memory max)*
- `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.memory.mb`
- `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.java.opts` *(...)*
- `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.queuename` *(in case you've got multiples queues with different priorities)*

---

Well, actually, the explanation above is not entirely true... On a HortonWorks distro you end up with 2 containers, as expected.
But with a **Cloudera distro**, you typically end up with just *one* container, running both the AM and the action in the same Linux process.

And I have no idea how they do that. Maybe there's a generic YARN config somewhere, maybe it's a Cloudera-specific feature.

Comment: BTW, you might find additional insights in these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538621/optimize-multiple-hive-ql-in-oozie ++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action ++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961310/oozie-java-action-why-property-oozie-launcher-mapred-child-java-opts-does-no/34005795 *(any many others on StackOverflow...)*